# Pandas: How to add an axis to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change shape of a dataframe from `(x,y)` to `(1,x,y)` or `(x,1,y)` or `(x,y,1)`. I know in numpy I can do something like `arr[np.newaxis,...]`, I wonder how can I achieve the same for a dataframe?

Comment: That is multiple index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pandas.panel` object is deprecated.  We use `pandas.MultiIndex` to handle higher dimensional data.

Consider the data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, list('abc'), list('xyz'))
df

   x  y  z
a  1  1  1
b  1  1  1
c  1  1  1
```

## Add Level

The following are various ways to add a level and dimensionality.

### `axis=0, level=0`

```
pd.concat([df], keys=['A'])

     x  y  z
A a  1  1  1
  b  1  1  1
  c  1  1  1
```

---

```
df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['B'], df.index]))

     x  y  z
B a  1  1  1
  b  1  1  1
  c  1  1  1
```

---

### `axis=0, level=1`

```
pd.concat([df], keys=['A']).swaplevel(0, 1)

     x  y  z
a A  1  1  1
b A  1  1  1
c A  1  1  1
```

---

```
df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, ['B']]))

     x  y  z
a B  1  1  1
b B  1  1  1
c B  1  1  1
```

---

### `axis=1, level=0`

```
pd.concat([df], axis=1, keys=['A'])

   A      
   x  y  z
a  1  1  1
b  1  1  1
c  1  1  1
```

---

```
df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['B'], df.columns]), axis=1, inplace=False)

   B      
   x  y  z
a  1  1  1
b  1  1  1
c  1  1  1
```

---

### `axis=1, level=1`

```
pd.concat([df], axis=1, keys=['A']).swaplevel(0, 1, 1)

   x  y  z
   A  A  A
a  1  1  1
b  1  1  1
c  1  1  1
```

---

```
df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['B']]), axis=1, inplace=False)

   x  y  z
   B  B  B
a  1  1  1
b  1  1  1
c  1  1  1
```